# What is wrong With This python code? It is a Menu which edits memory. ReadWriteMemory library

Tags: python

my code:

```
from ReadWriteMemory import ReadWriteMemory


def main():
    base_address = 0x7FF7B9B10000 #Backrooms-Win64-Shipping.exe
    static_address_offset = 0x04AE64E0 #the offset from base of t he static address of the pointer chain
    pointer_static_address = base_address +static_address_offset #"Backrooms-Win64-Shipping.exe"+04AE64E0
    offsets = [0x68, 0x28, 0x838, 0x10, 0x8D8]
    
    rwm = ReadWriteMemory()
    process = rwm.get_process_by_name('Backrooms-Win64-Shipping.exe')
    process.open
    my_pointer = process.get_pointer(pointer_static_address, offsets=offsets)
    pointer_value = process.read(my_pointer)
    print(f'Current Player Number: {pointer_value}')
    value_to_set = int(input('Enter A Value: '))
    process.write(my_pointer, value_to_set)
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

python 3.11.2

my error:

C:\Users\artur\OneDrive\Desktop\programming\Escape The Backrooms Mod Menu\Escupa Da Bakruums\MODMENU\V1>python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\artur\OneDrive\Desktop\programming\Escape The Backrooms Mod Menu\Escupa Da Bakruums\MODMENU\V1\main.py", line 21, in 
main()
File "C:\Users\artur\OneDrive\Desktop\programming\Escape The Backrooms Mod Menu\Escupa Da Bakruums\MODMENU\V1\main.py", line 13, in main
my_pointer = process.get_pointer(pointer_static_address, offsets=offsets)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\artur\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\ReadWriteMemory_*init*_.py", line 77, in get_pointer
temp_address = self.read(lp_base_address)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\artur\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\ReadWriteMemory_*init*_.py", line 100, in read
ctypes.windll.kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(self.handle, lp_base_address, lp_buffer,
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: OverflowError: int too long to convert

modules are imported properly, I tried running code through VSC and CMD.

Comment: Don't use that module, as it's full of bugs (*UB*).  [\[SO\]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546). Use other modules (*PyWin32* or *PSUtil* ?). Also there are other questions on this topic.